# Not able to load a model in the construct method in the controller of the Laravel 4 framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-4

Here is the beginning of my controller code:

```
<?php

class AppController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * App Model
     * @var app
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * User Model
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Inject the models.
     * @param app $app
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(App $app, User $user)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

In my models folder I have a file called App.php

Here is the beginning of the code:

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL; # not sure why i need this here :c
    use Robbo\Presenter\PresentableInterface;

    class App extends Eloquent implements PresentableInterface {
```

Now I did a var_dump() of the $this->app var and I got this:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\App)#472 (0) { }
```

I am not sure why it's trying to get a Facades when It's supposed to get my model.

Also here is a part of my routes file:

```
/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route model binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('app', 'App');
Route::model('role', 'Role');

# Apps - Second to last set, match slug
Route::get('{appSlug}', 'AppController@getView');
Route::post('{appSlug}', 'AppController@postView');

# Index Page - Last route, no matches
Route::get('/', 'AppController@getIndex');
```

I assume that the rest is irrelevant. But if not, do please ask for the rest.

Comment: well dont you need to specify which model??? Like...with an id, so the database knows which model to pull?  IE App::find(2);

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily use another class named App in Laravel, this is the name of the main system Facade (of Application.php). Take a look at Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php.

Comment: You're right it seems it has been reserved. I changed the name for a random one and it works. Write your answer and I will select it. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the IoC container. App is already taken by the main application. What you could do is add an alias in app/config/app.php

```
'aliases' => array(

    ... current aliases,

    'AppModel' => 'Robbo\Models\App'
);
```

Of course the App model needs to be namespaced to Robbo\Models in this case.